# R: header/colnames not taking the values from 1st row

Tags: r

I am trying to use the first row of my table as a column names (it is transposed table), but the values in the 1st row do not want to appear as a column headers, and I just get some strange numbers instead.

**I cannot set the column names manually as it is a part of my shiny app and names of the columns and their number differs

Here is sample data:

```
data <- structure(list(`1` = structure(c(1L, 30L, 37L, 24L, 32L, 26L), .Names = c("Seq", 
                                                                          "a", "b", "c", "d", 
                                                                          "e"), .Label = c(">1", "0", "0.02", "0.04", "0.05", 
                                                                                                         "0.06", "0.07", "0.08", "0.09", "0.14", "0.18", "0.20", "0.22", 
                                                                                                         "0.24", "0.25", "0.28", "0.40", "0.44", "0.47", "0.5", "0.50", 
                                                                                                         "0.52", "0.56", "0.66", "0.67", "0.88", "1.0", "1.03", "1.17", 
                                                                                                         "1.42", "1.73", "1018", "2.5", "2.6", "3.0", "3.00", "3.5", "4.0", 
                                                                                                         "4.5", "555", "702", "703", "995"), class = "factor"), `28` = structure(c(28L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                   30L, 34L, 22L, 2L, 27L), .Names = c("Seq", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "a", "b", "c", "d", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "e"), .Label = c(" 523", " 524", "0", "0.00", "0.02", "0.05", "0.08", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "0.09", "0.11", "0.13", "0.20", "0.27", "0.35", "0.39", "0.40", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "0.47", "0.48", "0.49", "0.5", "0.50", "0.55", "0.57", "0.69", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "0.72", "0.83", "0.95", "0.98", "1", "1.0", "1.67", "1.70", "2.0", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2.5", "3.5", "3.50", "4.0", "5.0", "503", "504", "510", "607", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "723", "725", "726", "729"), class = "factor"), `32` = structure(c(32L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    30L, 36L, 24L, 1L, 27L), .Names = c("Seq", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "a", "b", "c", "d", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "e"), .Label = c(" 586", " 587", "0", "0.00", "0.03", "0.06", "0.07", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "0.08", "0.09", "0.10", "0.12", "0.13", "0.19", "0.20", "0.26", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "0.30", "0.32", "0.35", "0.46", "0.48", "0.49", "0.5", "0.55", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "0.65", "0.67", "0.69", "0.94", "1.0", "1.00", "1.54", "1.74", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "2", "2.5", "2.50", "3.0", "3.5", "3.50", "4.0", "4.5", "464", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "5.0", "551", "552", "553", "554", "571", "572", "573"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "28", "32"), row.names = c("Seq", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "a", "b", "c", "d", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "e"), class = "data.frame")
```

and

```
colnames(data) <- data[1, ]
```

As i mentioned at the beginning (and above code shows it as well) that I would like the first row of the data to be the header of my data frame.

The result should look like that:

```
    >1    1    2
a   1.42 1.67 1.54
b    3.5  3.5  3.5
c   0.66 0.57 0.65
d   1018  524  586
e   0.88 0.98 0.94
```

why is not working?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What is the expected result? Please show the expected column names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your variables to character first,

```
data[] <- lapply(data, as.character)
names(data) <- data[1, ]
data <- data[-1,]
data
#    >1    1    2
#a 1.42 1.67 1.54
#b  3.5  3.5  3.5
#c 0.66 0.57 0.65
#d 1018  524  586
#e 0.88 0.98 0.94
```

If you want to keep the factors, then

```
names(data) <- unlist(data[1,])
```